# How can I linear increase to Location Value

Tags: animation, transforms

I want want to lineer increase to Location Value. 
How can i do that? 
For example i have a car and i need to go 100 meter. 
But i just know this car can go 20 meter. 
I want to go 20 meter and again 20 meter and again and agian. 
I don't want to go 100.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only need two keyframes to animate a value with a constant linear variance.

By default an fcurve uses a constant extrapolation, that is it stays at the last animated value. You can change this in the [Graph Editor](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/editors/graph_editor/introduction.html) or the [Dopesheet](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/editors/dope_sheet/introduction.html) in the *Channel->Extrapolation Mode* menu or <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd><kbd>E</kbd>.

[image: setting linear extrapolation]

If you want it to stop after a certain time, you can go to that frame and insert a new keyframe, then reset the extrapolation back to constant.